# regular expressions in jmeter. Change XPATH to regular expression extractor

Tags: jmeter

I am a newbie, I have been tasked to test the website. From the [page](http://apache.org/foundation/thanks.html)  I need the CSV file to add from the list all of the bronze sponsor(s) mask: [name of sponsor] : [link to the sponsor's website] . I used xpath[xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLHHH.png) includes a sampler [sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GnrP.png), but my teacher said to use regular expression extractor and you have to work with arrays of data from the response data.

My XPATH is:

```
.//*[@id="bronze"]/li[14]/a/@hred
```

How to change XPATH to regular expression?

Comment: you have the csv file with all the bronze sponsors name and link, now you have to verify if the response contains the following, this is what i get from this question, can you provide more info over this?